# Is there an algorithm problem like this accommodation problem

Tags: algorithm

Lets say for example that we have rooms and reservations for an hostal (where you can share room with other people), and we have the following data:

Reservations:

- Reservation for 2
- Reservation for 4
- Reservation for 3

Rooms:

- Room for 5
- Room for 4

Currently Im assigning the rooms according the order, taking the first smallest room, so in this case im assigning room for 4 to the reservation for 2, making this way that for the reservation for 4 would take the room for 5 and leaving the reservation for 3 out (the reservations cant be splitted).

Do you know if theres a problem like this or something similar?

Comment: Looks like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Answer (score 0):

This specific accommodation problem can be reduced to `n-sum problem`. allotment of a room depends on, if there's one or more reservation requests available to fill its total capacity. so combining n-sum and first-fit algorithm we can solve this.

Sample program: (Python)

```py
rooms=[5,4]
reservations=[4,3,2]

rooms.sort(reverse=True)
reservations.sort(reverse=True)

def nsum(arr,target,n):
    result=[]
    if n==0:
        result=[]
    elif n==1:
        for i in arr:
            if i==target:
                result.append([i])
                break
    elif n==2:
        table={}
        for i in arr:
            if target-i in table:
                result.append([i,target-i])
            else:
                table[i]=0
    else:
        for i in range(len(arr)):
            subsets=nsum(arr[i+1:],target-arr[i],n-1)
            for j in subsets:
                j.append(arr[i])
                result.append(j)
    return result

i=0
print("Rooms available: %s"%rooms)
print("reservation requests: %s"%reservations)
print("\nAllotments:")
while i<len(rooms):
    rlen=len(reservations)
    for j in range(1,rlen+1):
        fullfilled=nsum(reservations,rooms[i],j)
        if len(fullfilled)>0:
            for k in fullfilled[0]:
                reservations.remove(k)
                print("Room #%d (capacity %d) allotted for %d"%(i+1,rooms[i],k))
            rooms[i]=None
            break
    else:
        pass
        #print("Room#%d with capacity %d left empty"%(i+1,rooms[i]))
    i+=1

i=0
j=0
while i<len(rooms) and j<len(reservations):
    if rooms[i]!=None  and reservations[j]<=rooms[i]:
        print("Room #%d (capacity %d) allotted for %d"%(i+1,rooms[i],reservations[j]))
        rooms[i]=None
        reservations.remove(reservations[j])
        j+=1
    i+=1

print("\nRemaining rooms: %s"%[r for r in rooms if r!=None])
print("Remaining reservation: %s"%reservations)
```

Output:

```
Rooms available: [5, 4]
reservation requests: [4, 3, 2]

Allotments:
Room #1 (capacity 5) allotted for 2
Room #1 (capacity 5) allotted for 3
Room #2 (capacity 4) allotted for 4

Remaining rooms: []
Remaining reservation: []
```